# Read XML from R.xml and not as an XMLPullParser

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I want to pass my xmls from my `R.xml` directory to [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) library for deserialization.

The library accepts `Readers` and `InputSreams` and such.

But from `R.xml` I get `XMLPullParser`. How can I get something like a `Reader` or `InputStream` instead?

Answer (score 1):

if you save your `xml` fine inside `res/raw` instead of `res/xml`, you should be able to use `openRawResource`

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xml_name)
```

which returns an `InputStream`